# I think I'm going to step away for a bit

Tags: discussion

So, I tried to compartmentalize my issues in [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/this-castlevania-question-shouldnt-have-been-closed-as-game-identification), and I went overboard. I was angry and upset, and like all good internet drama my anger was way more than a handful of questions and a couple hundred internet points were worth. I stand by what I said, but it could have been phrased with less of an edge.

That said, I think that question and their responses are indicative that this site isn't for me. I've only managed to answer a handful of questions, most of which weren't particularly valuable in subjects that the community either doesn't know much about or actively dislikes, and the third of the questions I answered or tried to stand up for have resulted in more headaches than they're worth, oddly enough from everybody else on the site except the new person asking the question.

And every time I find a question I'd like to try and answer or something I'd like to learn, I have to stop and ask myself who I'm going to have to come to blows with today or if I'm dooming a question by trying to answer it. Aside from being stressful, frankly, there are better uses of everybody's time on the network.

So, I'm going to step away for a bit and focus on some other sites for a bit. I wish you all the best, and I honestly hope this site continues to run well. It's an awesome idea to maintain a collective knowledge repository on games, even if it doesn't include the knowledge I'd personally want archived.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry you had a bad experience here. I admired your passion, even if it got the best of you on your last post. Thank you for your contributions to the site, and best of luck with your future endeavours. Take care, hope to see you around.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answers you've contributed thus far.

I've also had questions where I disagree with the close-vote majority. It sucks, but that's how the site operates and stays organized.

Good luck in your endeavors!