# Should this question be edited, or should a new question be asked?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/342402/205290) was asked and answered today, a [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) question where a user quickly identified that the provided screenshot was from the game Metin 2. The asker commented on that answer to clarify that they *knew* the screenshot was from Metin 2, but that the dragon in the image is modded in from a different game and they want to know the original source.

I'm unsure whether this situation merits edits to clarify the question, or a new question to avoid invalidating the answer. Although editing a question to invalidate currently-correct answers is at-best highly discouraged, the current form of the question does ask "what game is this *dragon* from" rather than "what game is this *screenshot* from" and the body mentions "the original game of this model", which arguably means that the answer is already incorrect even though the question wasn't very clear about it.

Comment: so in short, here is the Problem if we make the person who questions happy, or the person wo answers happy. Another thing is, we can't be for sure that this question can be better answered because there is no other answer and the correct answer to his question is already given (that Metin 2 is the only Game where this dragon appear and the person who questions thinks wrong, which also can be happend)

Answer (score 4):

If a question is not clear enough to get the answers it's looking for, it should be edited to fix that.

That said, asking "Where did this model come from?" with no solid evidence of it being originally from a game [is off-topic for Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13068/where-do-we-stand-on-artifacts-the-asker-believes-are-from-a-game).

Comment: There's no way to solidly show it *isn't* from a game until identified.

Comment: @Draco18s Stack Exchange is not a court of law in the US; there's no presumption of innocence. In general you have to show that something is on-topic for it to be allowed.

Comment: [And even then](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/this-castlevania-question-shouldnt-have-been-closed-as-game-identification?noredirect=1#comment41707_13168)

Comment: If the asker has no basis or proof that the source is a different game, he can either accept the answer they have, or we can close it because we're right back where we started with ITG. The asker cannot be the only one to judge the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaning towards "edit the question" on this one. The title says "identify the dragon" and "original game of this model." It would have been helpful to know that the *screen shot* was from Metin 2, but adding that information doesn't invalidate the existing answer.

That said, if the original game is actually Metin 2 and the asker is wrong, that's an answer.